# How to clear Hadoop YARN cache using Ansible?

Tags: hadoop, ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to delete all cache folders in my Hadoop clusters. I wrote down already some steps, but I'm unsure how I should proceed with an Ansible script. Overall I understand Ansible, but I am a bit confused which modules I should use for my requirement.

**Steps:**

1. Stop the YARN services.

   ```
   $ sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop
   $ sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
   $ sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop
   ```
2. Log in to all nodes and delete the content of the user cache directories. For example:

   ```
   for i in cat list_of_nodes_in_cluster; do ssh $i rm -rf
   /prod/HDOP/data/13/daas.na/yarn/nm/usercache/*; done
   ```
3. Verify that all user cache directories in all nodes are empty.
4. Start the YARN services.

   ```
   $ sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start
   $ sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
   $ sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
   ```
5. Send the message "*YARN cache has been flushed.*" to our group ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Ansible playbook to execute your tasks.

1. Stop the YARN services.

   ```
   - name: service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop
     service: 
       name: hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver
       state: stopped

   - name: service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
     service: 
       name: hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
       state: stopped

   - name: service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop
     service: 
       name: hadoop-yarn-nodemanager
       state: stopped
   ```
2. Log in to all nodes and delete the content of the user cache directories.

   ```
   - name: delete the content of the usercache directories
      file: path="{{ item }}" state=absent
      with_fileglob:
          - /prod/HDOP/data/13/daas.na/yarn/nm/usercache/*
   ```
3. Verify that all user cache directories in all nodes are empty.

   ```
     - name:  Verify all usercache directories are empty.
       shell: /usr/bin/ls ~/soniya/ | wc -l
       register: total_size

     - debug:
            msg: "Directory total size is {{ total_size.stdout_lines }}"
           when: total_size.rc == 0
   ```
4. Start the YARN services.

   ```
   - name: service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start
     service: 
       name: hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver
       state: started

   - name: service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
     service: 
       name: hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
       state: started

   - name: service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
     service: 
       name: hadoop-yarn-nodemanager
       state: started
   ```

   5. send the massage as "YARN Cache has been flushed" to our group id

      you can use mail module for this.